# Error importing Tweepy with Python

Tags: python, twitter, web-crawler, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I've installed tweepy and have no problem with "import tweepy" being in my code. 
When I try to use anything in tweepy, however, I'm faced with the following error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'OAuthHandler'"

```
    from tweepy import OAuthHandler
    consumer_token = 'XXX'
    consumer_secret = 'YYY'
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret)
```

All solutions on stackoverflow say to try this, but it still does not work for me

```
    from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler
    consumer_token = 'XXX'
    consumer_secret = 'YYY'
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret)
```

Comment: In general, if you use `from xxx import yyy`, then you shouldn't use it as `xxx.yyy()` but just call `yyy()`. Otherwise it won't work. Only if you use `import xxx` should you use `xxx.yyy()`.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your file is named `tweepy.py` or there's a file/package nearby with the same name so Python tries to import `OAuthHandler` from the wrong location.

Try to rename the file, you can also change you code to:

```
import tweepy
print(tweeps)
```

to check the path and insure it's correct.

Comment: There is a file named tweepy.py that I had to install in order to get "import tweepy" to work. What file should I rename?

Comment: Could you please provide print output from my code above? It would be easier to figure out what file causes the problem.

Comment: This is the output I receive for your code (I assume you meant to say print(tweepy)):      <module 'tweepy' (namespace)>

Answer (score 0):

Which Python version are you using? try just with:

```
import tweepy
```

Comment: I'm using python 3. I've tried using "import tweepy" and I received this error: 
   NameError: name 'OAuthHandler' is not defined

Comment: how did you get tweepy? with pip?

Comment: I installed tweepy by doing the following:                                                  
1. Using the command prompt, navigate to where python files are stored
2. Type in the following exactly as shown:
git clone git://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
cd tweepy
python setup.py install

Comment: Ok, you could try install with pip from cmd like: pip install tweepy. I used Tweepy twice and always it worked fine. Besides, your problem could be that OAuthHandler is not in you installation.

Comment: If I use "pip install tweepy", can I open cmd and type that in right away, or do I need to change directories to get to my python folder first?

Comment: If you have pip installed and python in your Environment variable you can do that from anywhere. If you don't have it, you have to install pip and then, add python in your environment variables (in path) like this: C:\Python34\Scripts

Comment: I have python set an an environment variable but pip is not working. When I try to use pip I get "pip is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

Comment: Change directory to your python folder where pip is located (probably is the Scripts folder) and try there, right?

Comment: When I try to re-install pip in the folder where my python scripts are, I get this: " Requirement already up to date: pip in c:users\owner\appdata\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages". So it's saying I already have it, but when I try to use pip it says that "pip is not a recognized interal or external command....."

Comment: Go to your Python folder and open Scripts, is pip.py there? if yes, in the cmd open that folder (Scripts) and now run the command "pip install tweepy". If not, go to: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ and in the section *Installing with get-pip.py* right click on get-pip.py. [2] and select _save link as_, save the file and then just click rigth to open it and pip will install. I hope it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `OAuthHandler` is already imported, call it directly:

```
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why it works, but it did for me. first import tweepy and then separately OAuthHandler.
use both lines:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
```

and change other lines to:

```
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
```